# Number of days in the current month using iOS?

Tags: ios, datetime, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nscalendar

How can I get the current number of days in the current month using NSDate or something similar in Cocoa touch?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can use the `NSDate` and `NSCalendar` classes:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; //Get a date object for today's date
NSCalendar *c = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange days = [c rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                       inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit 
                      forDate:today];
```

`today` is an `NSDate` object representing the current date; this can be used to work out the number of days in the current month. An `NSCalendar` object is then instantiated, which can be used, in conjunction with the `NSDate` for the current date, to return the number of days in the current month using the `rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:` function.

`days.length` will contain the number of days in the current month.

Here are the links to the docs for [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html) and [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html) if you want more information.

Comment: I think you meant forDate:today

Comment: Yes I did, sorry, called it `date` when I was testing it in Xcode.

Comment: @Moshe. Yes. This can compute the range of any calendar unit in any larger calendar unit.

Comment: NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
 might be better for you than just [NSCalendar currentCalendar]

Answer (score 11):

Swift syntax:

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let days = cal.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, inUnit: .CalendarUnitMonth, forDate: date)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 syntax has changed a bit from Erez's answer:

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let monthRange = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: Date())!
let daysInMonth = monthRange.count
```

Answer (score 5):

`-[NSCalendar rangeOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:]`