# Getting the number of days of the month in NSDate in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

So i've been trying to find the last day of the month in an int but the code I'm using always thinks the last day is 30

[image: Last Day is January]

the code i am using looks like this

```
NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* compsd = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate]; // Get necessary date components

    // set last of month
    [compsd setMonth:[compsd month]+1];
    [compsd setDay:0];
    NSDate *tDateMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:compsd];
    //NSLog(@"%@", tDateMonth);

    //[comps setMonth:[comps month]+1];
    //[comps setDay:0];
   // NSDate *tDateMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
    //NSLog(@"%@", tDateMonth);
     //*/

    NSString *tDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tDateMonth];
    NSString *dateNTime = [[tDateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:2];
    int justDate = [[[dateNTime componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Last Day of %@ is %d", monthName, justDate);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of days in the current month using iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179945/number-of-days-in-the-current-month-using-iphone-sdk)

Comment: As @Fry has shown spending the time researching the APIs can save coding time.

Comment: What you're missing (among other things) is an understanding of how to use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: You use NSCalendar but never looked at the documentation to find `rangeOfUnit`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple way:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSRange rng = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                        inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                       forDate:[NSDate date]];
NSUInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = rng.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try something like this

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

[components setMonth:[components month]+1];
[components setDay:0];
NSDate *theDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
NSInteger dateInt = [dateString intValue];
NSLog(@"The int: %i", dateInt);
```